# Error returned while using Index and Match formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Index and Match to lookup a value on another worksheet within the same workbook, but I keep getting an error returned. (error 2042) I know I can do this using a formula, (see pic) but I'd like to use code. Does anyone mind taking a look?

[image]

```
    Dim WorkOrderDashboardCell As Range
Dim ProjectList As Worksheet
Dim ProjectNumber As String

Set ProjectList = Worksheets("Project List")

ProjectList.Activate

'We need to start by initializing values on the project list

    With ProjectList
        Dim LastRowProjectListSpreadsheet As Long
        LastRowProjectListSpreadsheet = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        Dim ProjectListNumbers As Range
        Set ProjectListNumbers = .Range("B2:B" & LastRowProjectListSpreadsheet)
         
        Dim ProjectListProjectNumber As Integer
        ProjectListProjectNumber = 2
         
    End With
    

    
'Switch back to the Dashboard spreadsheet
DashBoard.Activate

         Dim DashboardWorkOrderRange As Range
         Set DashboardWorkOrderRange = DashBoard.Range("E17:E" & LastRowProjectListSpreadsheet)


        For Each WorkOrderDashboardCell In Range("E17:E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ProjectNumber = Application.Index(ProjectListNumbers, Application.Match(WorkOrderDashboardCell, DashboardWorkOrderRange, 0))
        
        Debug.Print ProjectNumber
        Next
```

Comment: Your formula makes little sense. The match will be `1,2,3...169` and you are returning the values in the other sheet at those positions `B2,B3,B4...B170` of a much larger range `B2:B776`. Are you maybe trying to get the indexes at which each value in column `B` is found in column `E`? Or in which column of which sheet are you writing this formula? Please, do clarity.

Answer (score 0):

To use worksheet functions, use code like:

```
WorksheetFunction.Index
```

rather than:

```
Application.Index
```

You might also need to use the Address property of your ranges, like:

```
ProjectListNumbers.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line here is incorrect:

```
For Each WorkOrderDashboardCell In Range("E17:E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

You are trying to loop within a range, but this part of the aforementioned line returns a row number not a range of cells:

```
Range("E17:E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Change it to a range of cells.

Answer (score 0):

### Application.Match

- In your code you are using
  `Set DashboardWorkOrderRange = DashBoard.Range("E17:E" & LastRowProjectListSpreadsheet)` where `LastRowProjectListSpreadsheet` is possibly the wrong last row. Also you are using
  `For Each WorkOrderDashboardCell In Range("E17:E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` where `Range("E17:E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` is a row (instead of a range). Finally you are using `Application.Filter` without testing the result of `Application.Match`. Some other issues are the unnecessary use of `Activate` and the use of long variable names the latter seriously affecting the readability of the code.
- This is your code revised. When running it you will see that it makes little sense (mentioned in the comments).
- I'm posting it for you only to maybe easier find out what you really want to do.
- It is illustrating how the result of `Application.Match` should always be tested with `IsNumeric` (or `IsError`) and that you don't have to (in this case, should not) use `Application.Index`, but just the `Cells` property of the range object with the index returned by `Application.Match`, to return the desired value.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LittleSense()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    Dim plRng As Range
    With wb.Worksheets("Project List")
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set plRng = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    End With
    
    Dim dbRng As Range
    With wb.Worksheet("Dashboard")
        LastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        dbRng = .Range("E17:E" & LastRow)
    End With
    
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim dbIndex As Variant
    Dim plValue As Variant
    
    For Each cel In dbRng.Cells
        dbIndex = Application.Match(cel, dbRng, 0)
        ' You might as well do:
        'dbIndex = dbIndex + 1
        If IsNumeric(dbIndex) Then ' Not necessary: all values will be found.
            plValue = plRng.Cells(dbIndex).Value
            Debug.Print plValue & " (" & dbIndex & ")"
        Else
            ' Not necessary: all values will be found.
            Debug.Print "Not found " & "(""" & cel.Value & """)"
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```